# c# get set overwrite user in masterpage

Tags: c#, setter, getter

In my **MasterPage** in c# use the *get set property* for to be able to retrieve the email address of every user who accesses the website:

```
    public static string TheObjectPropertyEmail { get; private set; }    

    ...

    TheObjectPropertyEmail = reader["Email"].ToString();
```

On the page **Default.asp.cs** with *MasterPage* recovery the email address of every user who accesses the website with :

```
Mp.TheObjectPropertyEmail
```

But I have tried that if the access is performed by user with email **foo@foo.com** and after a few seconds the access is made with user with email **foo2@foo.com** ( contemporary accesses ) this second access overwrites the first access of **foo@foo.com** and the information of the last access to the website is displayed...

How to do resolve this ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Please can you help me ?

**Edit #01**

```
public static class MailContainer
    {
        public static string TheObjectPropertyEmail
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Session["TheObjectPropertyEmail"].ToString();
            }
            private set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["TheObjectPropertyEmail"] = value;
            }
         } 
    }

  MailContainer.TheObjectPropertyEmail = reader["Email"].ToString();
```

Comment: The TheObjectPropertyEmail should not be static in this case...

Comment: Thank you, I need delete static attribute  on public static string ? I don't understand sorry...

Comment: Why is TheObjectPropertyEmail  is static? static means there is a single instance of that variable. Maybe you need to have that variable per user and not static. you probably need some class per user and inside that class hold an email property of the user this class represents.

Comment: @ShayK I have tried deleting stati on the method but I have error *CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U must crate a public static class for access to variable.
Can't access TheObjectPropertyEmail in MasterPage because MasterPage class is not static.

```
namespace xxxxx
{
    public static class MailContainer
    {
        public static string TheObjectPropertyEmail
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Session["TheObjectPropertyEmail"].ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["TheObjectPropertyEmail"] = value;
            }
         } 
    }
}
```

use:

```
xxxxx.MailContainer.TheObjectPropertyEmail
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Please see **Edit 01** in my first question. I have this error *ERROR the property or indexer cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible*